# If $X$ and $Y$ are both independent standard normal random variables, then what is the distribution of $\frac{1}{2}\left(X^{2}-Y^{2}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

As $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal variate, therefore: $$X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)\hspace{.5cm} \text{let's call it}\hspace{.5cm}\chi_X^2(1)$$ $$\text&$$ $$Y^2 \sim \chi^2(1)\hspace{.5cm} \text{let's call it}\hspace{.5cm}\chi_Y^2(1)$$

As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are also independent. Thus, $\chi_X^2(1)$ and $\chi_Y^2(1)$ are independent.

We also know that if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables and $M(t)$ denotes the moment generating function of a given random variable then: $$M_{aX+bY}(t)=M_X(at)\cdot M_Y(bt)$$

As the MGF of $\chi^2(1)$ is $M(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$, we have

$$M_{\frac{\chi_X^2(1)}{2}+\frac{-\chi_Y^2(1)}{2}}(t) = M_{\chi_X^2}\Bigl(\frac{t}{2}\Bigr)\cdot M_{\chi_Y^2}\Bigl(\frac{-t}{2}\Bigr)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

which is not MGF of any distribution known to me. But the answer says it's actually $\frac{X^2-Y^2}{2} \sim exp(\lambda=1)$

Moreover, I am getting $\frac{X^2+Y^2}{2} \sim exp(\lambda=1)$ instead. As

$$M_{\frac{\chi_X^2(1)}{2}+\frac{\chi_Y^2(1)}{2}}(t) = M_{\chi_X^2}\Bigl(\frac{t}{2}\Bigr)\cdot M_{\chi_Y^2}\Bigl(\frac{t}{2}\Bigr)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2t}{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}^2}=\frac{1}{1-t}$$
which is MGF of $exp(\lambda=1)$

Am I doing something wrong or there is a misprint in question?

Comment: I would say that since $P(X^2-Y^2 < 0) > 0$, $X^2-Y^2$ is not exponentially distributed, so there's probably a misprint in the question.

Comment: $X^2 - Y^2$ is a symmetric distribution (in fact, $Z - Z'$ is a symmetric distribution for any pair of independent random variables $Z\sim Z'$). The support of a symmetric distribution will always contain positive and negative values (if $a$ is in the support, then so is $-a,$ for every $a$).